# How to access the docker embedded dns from outside the docker network

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dnsmasq

I run a dnsmasq-service in my docker network, which does -- by intent -- not forward queries towards the docker embedded dns but serves as a resolver for openvpn clients that are connected to an openvpn server in the same docker network.

Those openvpn clients require to talk to a third, proprietary service in the same docker network that they should discover by name. So I tried to add a route to the clients to 127.0.0.11 so that they can resolve the service name via the embedded dns. But it refuses to answer to them, what I saw using tcpdump. I assume that is because the embedded dns is not meant to serve other networks than the specific docker network.

I really want to make the docker embedded dns answer one of my ovpn-clients directly.

Is that somehow possible?

Thanks